# How I can change position of the blinking cursor in the code

Tags: after-effects, adobe

I have this text typing with blinking cursor, I used the effect type-on-text-preset on the text so it's typing with cursor, but I want to control this cursor, so I can scale it or change position or what ever I want....

The effect has a code as u see in the picture… so what I should do in the script, so I can control the cursor? All I want is control the cursor to change its position… Thank u all

[image]